# Upgrade spring boot version from 1.5.13 to 1.5.19 occurred Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping'

Tags: spring-boot

Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD

Comment: Can you provide the complete stack trace? Without knowing from where the `ExceptionInInitializerError` has been thrown, it's very difficult to know what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by adding the following to `pom.xml`:

```
<exclusion> 
   <groupId>xalan</groupId> 
   <artifactId>xalan</artifactId> 
</exclusion>
```

Maybe it shouldn't have xalan in the Maven dependencies.